# Comparing Object Prop Levels with Optional Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the type of question where I'm asking for guidance as I'm not sure if what I'm looking for exists...

**Context:**
I am using Firestore to save data and I'm building a re-usable custom hook (React 16.8) to use whenever I want to save data to my user object. When I use the hook, I will send what props need to be saved, but all props are optional. What I am trying to do is basically set the structure what my full Firestore object ***should*** look like on the client side and then compare the props parameter to make sure it follows the convention of the original.

Since all props are optional, I am only trying to compare the **level** of the keys, not equality of values. The original skeleton would look something like this:

firestore obj

```
{
    name,
    email,
    bio {
        summary,
        array,
        photo
    },
    something,
    more,
    much
}
```

and then when I click a save button in my app, I'll send props to my hook that may look like this (notice the incompleteness):

```
{
    email: 'new@email.com',
    bio: {
        photo: 'url.com/new/photo'
    }
}
```

The above object would pass the test. But if I pass props such as this:

```
{
    photo: 'url.com/new/photo'
}
```

my comparison would detect that `photo` is at the wrong level as it should be one level under `bio`.

So my question is, is there a concept/package that can help or is this something I might as well create from scratch?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: so you are asking for JSON schema or sort of. I just did not get if you need that for composing unit tests or for function's parameter validation

Comment: For a function's parameter validation

Comment: check [ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) or try another JSON schema [implementations](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'got a similar problem in the past, and  I d'idn't find anything for resolve it.
So, I have wrting my own function for this, And by chance for you, I finded this old code.
It did a little more than your question, as he also test if elements are on the sames type.
Here it is :

```js
const skeleton = { name:'',  email:'',  bio: { summary :'', array:[], photo:'' },
  something:'', more:'', much:'' };

var
  test1  = { email: 'new@email.com', bio: { photo: 'url.com/new/photo' } },
  test1b = { email: 'new@email.com', bio: { photo: 'url.com/new/photo', badThing: 25 } },
  test1c = { email: 'new@email.com', bio: [1,2,3] },
  test2  = { photo: 'url.com/new/photo'},
  testX  = 25;


console.log ('test 1 is conform ->'  , hasSamePlacedKeys(skeleton, test1 ));
console.log ('test 1b is conform ->' , hasSamePlacedKeys(skeleton, test1b ));
console.log ('test 1c is conform ->' , hasSamePlacedKeys(skeleton, test1c ));
console.log ('test 2 is conform ->'  , hasSamePlacedKeys(skeleton, test2 ));
console.log ('test X is conform ->'  , hasSamePlacedKeys(skeleton, testX ));



function hasSamePlacedKeys( refSkeleton, testObject )
{
  let
    objType = typeof(testObject),
    noErr   = ( objType==='object' && !Array.isArray(testObject) )
    ;

  for (let key in testObject )
  {
    noErr   = refSkeleton.hasOwnProperty(key);
    objType =  typeof(testObject[key]);

    if (noErr)
    { noErr = (objType === typeof(refSkeleton[key]) )  }

    if (noErr && objType==='object') {
      if ( Array.isArray(testObject[key]) )
      { noErr = Array.isArray(refSkeleton[key]) }
      else
      { noErr = hasSamePlacedKeys(refSkeleton[key], testObject[key] ) }
    }

    if (!noErr) break;
  }
  return noErr;
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is the exact function I was composing in my head! I'm thinking this is the best way to go.